# displaying label in swt table in eclipse rcp

Tags: label, eclipse-rcp

I have created a swt table and i don't know how to display the text in desired font. But i know how to do it in jlabel. I am having problem to add the jlabel to the swt.table.
For jLabel I have done like this :

```
String theString = "All the King's men";
JLabel theLabel = new JLabel(theString);
java.awt.Font theFont = new java.awt.Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 10);
theLabel.setFont(theFont);
```

So how to insert the label text to the table columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix SWT and AWT in this way. Instead, you should call `TableItem.setFont(Font)`. Note that it takes `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font` and not `java.awt.Font`!